# GameKit: GKSession manual

Tags: iphone, gamekit

I want to connect two devices using the GKSession, starting one as a server and the other one as a client. Using this configuration I can't use the GKPeerPickerController.

I'm having problems for connecting the two devices:

- Using only bluetooth: impossible
- using WiFi: at least there are some data exchange between the devices but no successfully conection.

In the interface file I have the

```
GKSessionDelegate
GKSession *session;
```

In the implementation, I start the server using this code:

```
session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"iFood"  displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeClient];
session.delegate = self;
session.available = YES;
```

The client starts using this code:

```
session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"iFood"  displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeServer];
session.delegate = self;
session.available = YES;
```

How I can force the use of Bluetooth instead of the WiFi ?

Also I have implemented those calls:

```
-(void)session:(GKSession *)session didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer:(NSString *)peerID {
NSLog(@"Someone is trying to connect"); 
}

- (BOOL)acceptConnectionFromPeer:(NSString *)peerID error:(NSError **)error {
NSLog(@"acceptConnectionFromPeer");
}
```

When I start, I get this into the debugger:

```
Listening on port 50775
2010-02-19 14:55:02.547 iFood[3009:5103] handleEvents started (2)
```

And when the other device starts to find, I get this:

```
~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=187f70, Flags=2, IFIndex=2 (name=[en0]), ErrorType=0 name=00eGs1R1A..Only by Audi regtype=_2c3mugr67ej6j7._udp. domain=local.
~ DNSServiceQueryRecord callback: Ref=17bd40, Flags=2, IFIndex=2 (name=[en0]), ErrorType=0 fullname=00eGs1R1A\.\.Only\032by\032Audi._2c3mugr67ej6j7._udp.local. rrtype=16 rrclass=1 rdlen=18 ttl=4500
** peer 1527211048: oldbusy=0, newbusy=0
~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=187f70, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 name=00eGs1R1A..Only by Audi regtype=_2c3mugr67ej6j7._udp. domain=local.
GKPeer[186960] 1527211048 service count old=1 new=2
~ DNSServiceQueryRecord callback: Ref=17bd40, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 fullname=00egs1r1a\.\.only\032by\032audi._2c3mugr67ej6j7._udp.local. rrtype=16 rrclass=1 rdlen=18 ttl=7200
** peer 1527211048: oldbusy=0, newbusy=0
~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=187f70, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 name=00TF5kc1A..Only by Audi regtype=_2c3mugr67ej6j7._udp. domain=local.
~ DNSServiceQueryRecord callback: Ref=188320, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 fullname=00tf5kc1a\.\.only\032by\032audi._2c3mugr67ej6j7._udp.local. rrtype=16 rrclass=1 rdlen=18 ttl=7200
** peer 1723356125: oldbusy=0, newbusy=0
~ DNSServiceQueryRecord callback: Ref=188320, Flags=2, IFIndex=2 (name=[en0]), ErrorType=0 fullname=00TF5kc1A\.\.Only\032by\032Audi._2c3mugr67ej6j7._udp.local. rrtype=16 rrclass=1 rdlen=18 ttl=4500
** peer 1723356125: oldbusy=0, newbusy=0
```

What I'm missing here ?

I'm sure that both devices have bluetooth enabled and connected into the same WiFi.

thanks,

r.

Comment: FYI, your GKSessionModeClient and GKSessionModeServer are swapped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss to accept connection with client. After you receive the "didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer" callback, you need to accept connection with client like this:

```
-(void)session:(GKSession *)session didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer:(NSString *)peerID {
  NSLog(@"Someone is trying to connect"); 
  NSError *error;
  [gkSession acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:&error];
  if(error)
    NSLog(@"Error on accept connection with peer: ", error);
}
```

After this you will receive "GKPeerStateConnected" here:

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state{}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems, but from the description above I think you are making some
errors:

GKSession only implements BT; if you use the picker, then you can provide
separate methods for dealing with WiFi connections.

The "didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer" method should *call* the
"acceptConnectionFromPeer" method *on the session object* -- you do
not implement the "acceptConnectionFromPeer" on your delegate.

For debugging, you should log state changes in the delegate method
"session:peer:didChangeState:"
(see http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSessionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html ).  When a peer is "Available", you
can call "connectToPeer:"; when "Connected", you can use "sendData:toPeers:".

For IO after you have established a connection, you want to have called
the "setDataReceiveHandler:withContext:" method on the session.

Earlier I had some typos in my code but it is now working.

Good luck.

Comment: Hello,

I have those delegates methods implemented, but I didn't write them to the code.

Also my session:peer:didChangeState never get calls when using GKSession, but it gets called when I use the picker.

Until I found more info about what can be wrong or why it's not working, I'm using the GKPicker ...

thanks, at least I know I'm not the only one ...

:-)

regards,

r.

Comment: "GKSession only implements BT" ... this isn't true.

Comment: @type While this is true now, I believe at the time this answer was given `GameKit` only had support for bluetooth connections and you had to use `CFNetwork` to connect devices over WiFi. It would be more accurate to say "This is no longer true as `GameKit` now supports WiFi connections."

Comment: I used GameKit during the 4.0 betas. GKSession has always supported Wifi and BT. I think you may be thinking of Apple's UI kit for GameKit which only assists with BT connections. You have to create your own GKSession instance if you want to use Wifi, but it does "support" it.